# Analytic composition of an analytic function and unknown function for Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, riemann-surfaces

Consider the following statement:

> Suppose $f: S_1\to S_2$ and $g: S_2\to S_3$ are nonconstant maps.
> Suppose that both $h = g\circ f: S_1\to S_3$ and $f: S_1\to S_2$ are
> analytic. Then $g$ is analytic as well.

I know this is true when $S_1,S_2,S_3$ are planar regions. For example, see the answer here: [If composition of one function and the other holomorphic function is holomorphic, then the other should be holomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206652/if-composition-of-one-function-and-the-other-holomorphic-function-is-holomorphic?rq=1)

The argument is basically just finding a locally-defined branch of $f^{-1}$ and observing $g = h\circ f^{-1}$ on this local neighborhood (though one needs to do extra work at critical points of $f$). I believe the statement also generalizes to the case where $S_1,S_2,S_3$ are Riemann surfaces by working in local coordinates. Does anyone know a reference discussing this situation? I want to use this for an unrelated problem, so I am hoping there is a book or paper I can cite instead of writing out all the details myself.

Comment: The statement is not true as stated.

Comment: Really? That's surprising. Do you have a counterexample? Is there a missing technical requirement (like $f$ being surjective), or is there a more fundamental issue?

Comment: Precisely $f$ is not surjective, so you can't say anything about $g$ on the piece of $S_2$ where $f$ doesn't hit.